# Song picker for Android

Tags: android, media, mpmediapickercontroller

Is there a song picker for Android that can be invoked programatically?

I'm looking for something similar to iPhone's MPMediaPickerController, which shows a view from where the user can select songs.

Comment: Mayebe this is something for you: http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/RockLock/src/com/marvin/rocklock/SongPicker.java?r=609

Answer (score 15):

You can send an intent of type "ACTION_PICK" or "ACTION_GET_CONTENT".  For example:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.setType("audio/*");
    Intent c = Intent.createChooser(i, "Select soundfile");
    startActivityForResult(c,1);
```

see here for more info:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Comment: Beware, not every application has a picker. I just got a crittercism report that the activity wasn't found on a customer device.