# How do I pick multiple items from music player?

Tags: android

I need to call music player from my activity to choose multiple song items and return that list to my activity. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. Only thing you can perform - launch music picker for one song. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179908/song-picker-for-android) to see how to do it.